# add a range of objects from one array to another

Tags: ios, arrays, swift

Currently we have 2 arrays:

```
  fileprivate var totalDrinksArray: [CocktailModel] = []
  fileprivate var currentDrinksArray: [CocktailModel] = []
```

What I'm trying to do is get the first 2 objects of the `totalDrinksArray` and add them to the `currentDrinksArray`.  After a button is pressed the next 2 drinks will be added from the `totalDrinksArray` to the `currentDrinksArray` (for a total of 4 drinks )and so on.

Comment: Note that it is not recommended to add the object type to their names.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Array method `func prefix(_ maxLength: Int)` which will return a slice of the total array (up to n elements) or less if there is not enough elements and append the contents to your current array or insert it at the desired index:

```
currentDrinksArray.append(contentsOf: totalDrinksArray.prefix(2))
```

Or if you would like to insert them in the beginning of your array:

```
currentDrinksArray.insert(contentsOf: totalDrinksArray.prefix(2), at: 0)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can "add" arrays together:

```
currentDrinksArray += totalDrinksArray[0...1]
```

should work.

Not quite clear from your question, but if you want to "add the next two" (the 3rd and 4th):

```
currentDrinksArray += totalDrinksArray[2...3]
```

Answer (score 0):

Simplest safe solution IMO:

```
var currentIndex = 0
func addDrinks() {
    if(currentIndex + 2 >= totalDrinksArray.count) {
        currentDrinksArray += totalDrinksArray[currentIndex...]
    }
    else {
        currentDrinksArray += totalDrinksArray[currentIndex..<(currentIndex + 2)]
    }
    currentIndex += 2
}
```